# how can i make my random text generator not repeat until all texts have been displayed?

Tags: random, arc4random

.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {


IBOutlet UILabel *textview;
```

}

```
-(IBAction)random;
```

.m

```
-(IBAction)random{
int text = arc4random() % 24;
switch (text) {
    case 0:
        textview.text = @"example 1";

        break;

    case 1:
        textview.text = @"example 2";

        break;

    case 2:
        textview.text = @"example 3";

        break;

    case 3:
        textview.text = @"example 4";

        break;

    case 4:
        textview.text = @"example 5";

        break;

    case 5:
        textview.text = @"example 6";

        break;

    case 6:
        textview.text = @"example 7";

        break;
```

etc...
i just want it not to repeat like example 1, 3,6,2,5,4,7 or something like that and then start over without repeating the same thing twice unless all texts have been displayed 
thanks in advance